# How to open a new year's letter to customers?

Tags: business-writing, letter

I am looking for suggestions on how to open a letter to my customers in the new year. I personally couldn't care less about Christmas or new year's, but it is the accepted social norm.

> Hello {customer name}, happy new year, I hope you had a refreshing break...

That sounds a little awkward and gammy. Does anyone have any suggestions?

Comment: Hi Jeremy. I tweaked the title of your question a little to try to better summarize what you're asking about. Feel free to [Edit] further.

Answer (score 1):

It's always tricky writing something when you don't believe the sentiments yourself, and this can sometimes come across to the reader.

I would stick with what I wanted to say. If the purpose of the letter is to encourage the customer to make further enquiries or orders, something like :

> We would like to take the opportunity to wish you every success for
>   2018

or

> We are looking forward to continuing our work together in the new year

would be closer to what I think the letter would be intending to do, would look forward rather than backward, and would avoid any reference to a holiday (which the customer might not have had, or which might have gone badly).